# Python recursion error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment. Shuffling deck python code

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo, discrete-mathematics

Top-to-random is a simplistic shuffling method where you take the top card from the deck and put it in a random position in the deck, each position being equally likely. (Therandom position can include leaving it at the top of the deck.).For example, suppose we have a deck containing cards numbered 0 through 9. Imagine that initially, the position of the cards is (from top to bottom):0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Then after one top-to-random shuffle, the order might be 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 7 8 9so that1is now at the top.  At first, the deck will not be very random.  But with many repetitions, it will become uniformly random. Why? Eventually, some cards will be placed after the 9. And after that, eventually, a second card will be placed after the 9. The second will be equally likely to be placed before or after the first. In this way, although the cards before the 9 may not be uniformly random, the two cards after the 9 will be. Slowly, the stack of uniformly random cards after the 9 grows, until the 9 reaches the top of the deck, and the 9 is inserted uniformly randomly, and at that point, the deck becomes uniformly random.

```
import numpy as np

user = int(input("Number of cards: "))
list1 = []
for i in range(user):
    list1.append(i)
print("Initial: ",list1) 
n = int(input("Number of times to shuffle: "))

def top_to_random(list1):

    if n == 0:
        return null
    else:
        first = list1[0]
        x = np.random.randint(len(list1)+1)
        list1.insert(x, first)
        list1.pop(first)
        print(list1)
        n -= 1
    return top_to_random(list1)

print(top_to_random(list1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `n` a parameter solves your issue.

```py
def top_to_random(list1, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 
    else:
        first = list1[0]
        x = np.random.randint(len(list1)+1)
        list1.insert(x, first)
        list1.pop(first)
        print(list1)
        n -= 1
    return top_to_random(list1, n)

print(top_to_random(list1, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'n' does not exist inside your function. You can do this:

```
def top_to_random(list1):
    n = int(input("Number of times to shuffle: "))

    if n == 0:
        return None
    else:
        first = list1[0]
        x = np.random.randint(len(list1)+1)
        list1.insert(x, first)
        list1.pop(first)
        print(list1)
        n -= 1
    return top_to_random(list1)


print(top_to_random(list1))
```

Or you could pass on the variable into the function `top_to_random(list1, n)`